# Absolute value with MongoDB aggregation framework

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm using the MongoDB aggregation framework and need to take the absolute value of an amount field, which I use in both the project portion and the group portion, ex:

```
'$project' => {
          'amount' => 1,
          '_id' => 0
        }
```

....

```
    '$group' => { 
      'total' => {'$sum' => '$amount'}
    }
```

How do you take the absolute value of the 'amount' field in this case?  I wasn't able to find it in the docs (maybe it's not available?)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not directly available, but you can do it using a `$cond` operator and a `$subtract` within a `$project` like this (as a JavaScript object):

```js
{ $project: {
  amount: {
    $cond: [
      { $lt: ['$amount', 0] },
      { $subtract: [0, '$amount'] }, 
      '$amount'
    ]
}}}
```

So if `amount < 0`, then `0 - amount` is used, otherwise `amount` is used directly.

**UPDATE**

As of the **3.2** release of MongoDB, you can use the new [`$abs`](https://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/operator/aggregation/abs/#exp._S_abs) aggregation expression operator to do this directly:

```js
{ $project: { amount: { $abs: '$amount' } }
```

Comment: Or, as an alternative, you should be able to `$multiply` by `-1`: `{ $multiply: [-1, '$amount'] }`

Comment: @AshutoshPriyadarshy ((-1)*(-1))/(-1) is still -1, so that is incorrect.