# Find documents with difference between field and value less than x

Tags: mongodb

Suppose I have this documents:

```
{_id:1, value:2.21}
{_id:2, value:2.23}
```

Then if for example I receive a parameter which is 2.24, I want to return documents where abs(2.24-value)<=0.01 This concretely would return only the document with _id:2

So in general I want documents where abs(value-parameter)<=x

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not make the ABS operation directly. But you can do with a conditional operator `$cond`.

```
db.numbers.aggregate([{
   $project: {
            value: {
                $subtract: [2.24, 
                            {$cond: [{$lt: ['$value', 0]}, 
                                     {$subtract: [0, '$value']}, 
                                     '$value']
                            }
                ]
            }
        }
    }, {
    $match: {
          value: {$lte: 0.01}
    }
}]);
```

Use the `aggregate` command to perform the operation, the first step is done the projection of the absolute value, and the second step is done the condition.

Note that you may need to round off the absolute result to obtain the expected result.

Comment: This answer is fairly clearly based on [the answer to this question about absolute values](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17561804/absolute-value-with-mongodb-aggregation-framework). But this question does not require the use of absolute values. Using the aggregation pipeline in this way will perform the `$project` operation on ALL documents. This would end up being a costly and unnecessary step especially in large collections.

Answer (score 4):

This can be a simple `db.coll.find()` with [`$gte`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) and [`$lte`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lte/)

```
> var foo = 2.24;
> var difference = 0.0100000000001
> db.numbers.find({value:{$gte: (foo - difference), $lte: (foo + difference)}})
{ "_id" : 2, "value" : 2.23 }
```

The only issue is that MongoDB uses floating point arithmetic which means that if `difference` was set to 0.01, the result of `foo - difference` might be something like 2.23000000000000004 (which would miss the second document). That's why I set it just barely above the difference that we're actually looking for.